# VSCode breaks my powerShell associations once a ps1 file is opened with that editor

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, file-extension, powershell-7.0

I have a strange problem with Visual Studio code related to selecting the default Powershell version: I have installed Powershell 5.1 and 7 parallely, but when I doubleclick on a ps1-file, it should automatically run the Powershell 5 console and execute the script.

This works flawlessly on my computer. However, as soon as I right-click a ps1-file and select "Open with" -> "VSCode", the file is opened in VS Code. When I now close VSCode and doubleclick the ps1-File in Windows Explorer again, the file will be opened in VSCode instead  of Powershell 5 console, which is not my expected behaviour.

I believe that VSCode somehow changes the default handler for ps1-files from 5 to 7 in some way.

I have already tried to select the Windows powerShell as the default powerShell Extension in VSCode (by Clicking the plus button in the Terminal Window, Select Default Profile, and select Windows Powershell). This change seems to be completely ignored in VSCode, because I see from the console output that it always wants to open the ps1 file using PowerShell 7, instead of 5.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this unexpected behaviour? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem *interactively*:

- In File Explorer, right-click on a `.ps1` file and select `Open with > Choose another app`.
- In the dialog that opens, click on `Choose an app on your PC`
- Navigate to `powershell.exe` or paste its full path, typically `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and submit.
- Click on `Always`

This persistently causes `.ps1` files to be opened with `powershell.exe`, though the automatically created command line needs tweaking for full robustness / additional customizations, such as wanting to keep the resulting PowerShell session alive and the window open:

- Run `regedit.exe` and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command`
- Edit that key's default value by placing `-File` before `"%1"` to ensure that script files whose paths contain spaces are properly opened.
- Optionally, if you want to keep the session and window open after the script finishes executing, place `-NoExit` before `-File`